# Log of negative numbers

Tags: logarithms

I know that log of negative numbers is complex numbers. But I just got over this little proof and wondering what is wrong with this?
$$\log(-a)=\frac{2\times\log(-a)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\log(a^2)=\frac{2}{2}\log(a)=\log(a)$$

Comment: $\log (ab) = \log a + \log b$ does not hold for negative real numbers or for arbitrary complex numbers. I think there were similar questions.

Comment: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ has been used for $\log(a^2)$, where a is a positive real number. So there is no problem of complex number here.

Comment: Sure it is. You applied that "rule" to the numbers $-a$ and $-a$ ...

Comment: Compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370080/product-rule-for-logarithms-works-on-any-non-zero-value.

Comment: ok, thanks Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the property is actually $$\ln(x^a)=a\ln(\vert x\vert)$$ (for even integer a), and not$$\ln(x^a)=a\ln(x)$$ and since no number has a negative absolute value, the second equality is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first formula? It seems wrong to me e.g. for $a = 1$ and $x < 0$.

Comment: Oops, made a mistake. This applies to even integer powers, not all powers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's cut the complex plane along the positive real axis and work on the Riemann sheet for which

$$0\le \arg{z}<2\pi \tag 1$$

For $a$ real-valued with $a>0$, we have

$$\log (-a) =\log a +i\pi \tag 2$$

Now, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log (-a)&=\frac{2\log(-a)}{2}\\\\
& =\frac12 \log a^2 +i\pi \\\\
&=\log a +i \pi \\\\
&\ne \log a
\end{align}$$

In fact, if we multiply Equation $(2)$ by a factor of $2$, we get

$$2\log(-a)=\log a +i2\pi \ne \log a$$

That is, in multiplying by $2$, we actually move to the subsequent Riemann surface since Equation $(1)$ restricts the argument to be less than $2\pi$.

**CONCLUSION:**

> $n\log z \ne \log z^n$ in general.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: This is a great proof.

Comment: @MichaelEjercito Thank you.   Much appreciated